# Reporting Services Matrix Order

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

I've got a reporting services report which display data in a matrix.

The matrix rows are ordered by the report on a specific field's value.

Trouble is I want a particular value to always appear last in the matrix even though it won't naturally be ordered there. Is there a way I can do this using an expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a virtual column to your query result that stores your favorite order value. it means you must give a order value to your records manually then order your result by this value.

maybe this be a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too hard. Sort first by an expression like `=if(THAT_FIELD = THE_VALUE_I_WANT, 1, 0)` which will evaluate to 1 for the value you want, and 0 for anything else, therefore putting the value you're interested in last. Then sort by THAT_FIELD second.